# Aws Aurora cannot connect to Primary instance after replica is promoted

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have a Multi-AZ Aurora MySql Cluster. When i first created it, I could connect my local apps to the Cluster Endpoint and interact with it just fine. At some point my Read only instance got promoted and I was no longer able to connect to the cluster endpoint.

If I get on MySql Workbench and enter the Reader endpoint, I can log in to it. From there I can view the tables and rows, but obviously I cant perform inserts/updates/deletes.

If I use the same credentials to try to connect to the Writer endpoint or connect directly to the Cluster endpoint, it times out and says it couldnt connect.

The first time this happened I couldnt find an answer so I just created a new cluster and essentially started over. It worked for a few weeks and then the same thing happened.

My Aurora Instance is in a VPC, but the Security Group is configured for public access via CIDR "0.0.0.0/0". I realize that isnt ideal but I am simply trying to get this to work at the moment. I know the Security Groups and VPN were configured appropriately because I was able to connect to the cluster until today.

Has anyone had this experience before? Have you managed to resolve it? Thanks

Comment: Are your instances on different subnets?  If so, have you verified that both subnets have the same route tables and the same network ACL settings?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I noticed yesterday that my Subnet Group contained a private subnet. I removed it from the list and eventually things started to work properly again. I dont know if that is exactly what the problem was but ill update this post in a week if it still works. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: @bsayegh did you faced the same issue again ?